# Change in expectation due to Bayesian update

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expected-value, radon-nikodym

Consider a prior $P$ on some finite set $X$, and a posterior $Q$ on $X$ formed via a Bayesian update of $P$ given some data $y$.

I am interested in finding alternative ways to write the following difference of expectations
$$E_Q[X]-E_P[X]$$
that use the fact that $Q$ is a Bayesian update of $P$.

I have been looking into Radon-Nikodym derivatives but I am not sure how to use them here.

Comment: Curious, what leads you to think that this is the sort of thing that can have a nice expression without further assumptions?

Comment: @ted I suppose I’m not looking for something necessarily simple, but rather some other forms that may rely on the Bayesian update relationship between the distributions (hopefully this structure gives us something compared to the general case of $P$ and $Q$ being arbitrary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, with RN derivative you only can say:

$$\mathbf{E}_Q[X]-\mathbf{E}_P[X]=\mathbf{E}_P\left[X\left(\frac{dQ}{dP}-1\right)\right]=\mathbf{E}_Q\left[X\left(1-\frac{dP}{dQ}\right)\right]$$

When Q is the Bayesian update of P, $\frac{dQ}{dP}$ is proportional to the likelihood of the sample $y$.

Comment: Thank you. Question: is the equivalence $E_P[XdQ/dP]=E_Q[X]$ similar to the tower rule of conditional expectation (e.g., $E[X]=E[E[X|Y]]$)?

Comment: Mmm I don't think so. It is a substitution in Lebesgue integral $\int X \frac{dQ}{dP} dP=\int X dQ$. If you think in absolutly continious random variables (densities) or discrete random variables it is to multiply and divide by pdf or pmf.